# I downloaded tow ubuntu box for vagrant but why it is a .tar file?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

I wanted to install an ubuntu box so I installed vagrant and virtual box. after trying to add a box using `vagrant box add ubuntu/bionic64` or `ubuntu/xenial64` I ended up with error that there is no default provider. so I went to download a bionic box file from this url:

```
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/current/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant.box
```

but after it is completed a .tar file is created on my disk which is not what I expected. that should be a `.box` file not a `.tar` file. inside the tar file there are these files:

```
ubuntu-bionic-18.04-cloudimg.mf
metadata.json
box.ovf
Vagrantfile
ubuntu-bionic-18.04-cloudimg-configdrive.vmdk
ubuntu-bionic-18.04-cloudimg.vmdk
```

what should I do with this file? I tried to change the extension and add it using the same command but no luck. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The `.box` file that you need is here:

https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/bionic64

Follow the instruction on the page. You don't really need to get the `.box` file because vagrant will do it for you automatically, and then vagrant will extract the `.box` file contents into `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-bionic64/<version>/virtualbox`

The files above will appear here. When you use the box in a `Vagrantfile`, vagrant will use the extracted box content to spin up the new virtual machine for you.

Read the vagrant documentation again.